# HTML/CSS Div Extend beyond parent div on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if the following is possible.  Have a `<button>` enclosed in a `<div>` which is enclosed in a parent `<div>`.  On hover of the child `<div>` have a dropdown info panel that displays information like email and phone number.  I've been working on this for a while (see my fiddle link below), but I can't get the drop down to appear anywhere outside of the parent `<div>` and moreover, the drop should appear directly below the button as opposed to on top of the button itself.

The button name is "Contact"

https://jsfiddle.net/wtj51d2f/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .navbar class overflow:hidden is preventing from content going beyond, I just try removing that value, and adding some top: 50px on your .drop-content class, and it is showing good.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much exactly what it should look like.  Any tips on how to get the left sides of `.drop-content` and `.button` aligned?

Comment: What do you mean? Container border's or text itself?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, just had to add a `left: 100px` to the `.drop-content` css modifier

Answer (score 1):

The .drop-content has to be a child of the .dropdown element in order to be directly manipulated by it in CSS. You can use JavaScript or jQuery to accomplish this effect, or refactor the page so that .drop-content stays within the .dropdown div.

This is what the jQuery might look like:

```
$('.dropdown').mouseover(function(){
    $('.drop-content').show();
});
```